# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, kryo

I am using Spark, GraphX 2.0.2 and IntelliJ.
I got the error:

```
Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl
```

So I added:

```
kryo.register(classOf[GraphImpl[Object,Object]])
```

but I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is solved with:

```
kryo.register(Class.forName("scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1", false, getClass().getClassLoader()))
```